# Assign PTS to packet based on position in stream

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mpeg, mpeg2-ts, transport-stream

I have a TS with a video and metadata stream. The video has correctly set PTS values, while the metadata does not (ffprobe gives N/A for each). However, the metadata packets are positioned correctly in the stream.

Is there a way I can assign the metadata packets a PTS based on their position in the stream. The exact precision is not important, as long as the PTS is somewhere in between the last and next video frame. As a last resort I will have to write some C code to do it, but I wanted to see if the ffmpeg frontend can do it.

I need to do this because I need to offset one stream relative to the other and '-itsoffset' does not appear to work, which I gather is due to the lack of PTS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with default tools. I had to write an app using libav/ffmpeg to do it